# Wordpress Redirect page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I search several times but I couldn't find nothing that really helps me.

Basically I have a very VERY simple Theme which is working very well.

I also have a database with some IP's and depending by this IP I need to redirect the guest to different pages.

So on my template index.php file I added:

```
if ($country == "br") { 
    echo "case1";
} else {
    $location = bloginfo('template_url')."/index-nbr.php";
    echo $location;

    ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          window.location= <?php echo "'" . $location . "'"; ?>;
       </script>
    <?php
}
```

I tried many different ways to redirect but none of them work. Could someone help me with this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

**Ok let me make your life easier.**

Just install this plugin you will find a text box on the bottom of every page in `PAGES` section in Admin panel where you can put your desired link/URL of the page and that will redirect you to your inserted URL.

[Page Link to Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/)